# Crashlytics report is not showing on firebase console

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, crashlytics

After showing

> "[Firebase/Crash][I-CRA000004] Successfully initialised"

in the xcode console.No crash report is submitted, even after crashing the application and firebase console is showing

> "App detected we're waiting for a crash"
> [enter image description here]
> https://i.stack.imgur.com/CJmlG.png

We have followed every step as per the firebase doc

1. We have added google service info.plist.
2. We have added the script along with its input files.
3. We have added "${PODS_ROOT}/FirebaseCrashlytics/run" script in the end
4. We have tried both cocoa pods and packages

[enter image description here]
https://i.stack.imgur.com/jZcW4.png

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SQ4wC.png)

Answer (score 1):

Install `FirebaseCrashlytics` instead of `FirebaseCrash`.

The initialization message posted comes from the deprecated FirebaseCrash instead of the supported FirebaseCrashlytics.

Share the Podfile if you're still stuck.

Comment: I have used : pod 'Firebase'
    pod 'Firebase/Messaging'
    pod 'Firebase/Crashlytics'
    pod 'FirebaseAuth'
    pod 'FirebaseFirestore'

Comment: After install FirebaseCrashlytics logs are showing [Firebase/Crashlytics][I-CLS000000] Crash reporting could not be initialized

Comment: You may want to open an issue at https://github.com/firebase/firebase-ios-sdk/issues with all of the information requested by the issue template

Answer (score 0):

You might need to set up Xcode to upload dSYM files to firebase to see the crashes on firebase dashboard else those will be there in the dSYMS section. You can see the steps here to set up Xcode for this  - https://firebase.google.com/docs/crashlytics/get-started?platform=ios.